# Calculate Model Accuracy for one of the Kaggle Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

How to calculate accuracy for PyTorch model used inhttps://www.kaggle.com/code/andradaolteanu/whales-dolphins-effnet-train-rapids-clusters

I tried using some methods like -

1. Tried this →
   `correct += (out == targets).float().sum() accuracy = 100 * correct / len(test)`
   This is giving weird errors ,i.e,

   > RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
   > /tmp/ipykernel_33/896230284.py in 
   > ----> 1 train_pipeline(train)
   > /tmp/ipykernel_33/2939766947.py in train_pipeline(train)
   > 62 #                 print(targets)
   > 63
   > ---> 64                 correct += (out == targets).float().sum()
   > 65 #                 num_corrects = num_corrects  + torch.sum(out.argmax(1) == targets)
   > 66
   > **RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (15587) must match the size of *tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 1***

   2. Tried this →
      `num_corrects = num_corrects + torch.sum(out.argmax(1) == targets) print(“Accuracy = {}”.format(train_accuracy))`
      This is giving 0 as accuracy and printing out and targets giving me this

   > **out**
   > tensor([[-13.0885, -15.4269, -15.7011,  ..., -18.2123, -21.8597, -19.1524],
   > [-13.3293, -12.2672, -14.0315,  ..., -17.7681, -22.0472, -18.1889],
   > [-14.6508, -13.7065, -16.5062,  ..., -19.2380, -21.8163, -19.5815],
   > ...,
   > [-15.3698, -16.0767, -14.8986,  ..., -18.8057, -22.7389, -19.4303],
   > [-13.5040, -14.4153, -15.7141,  ..., -19.5422, -22.9803, -19.5026],
   > [-13.8497, -15.1122, -14.3879,  ..., -19.5625, -22.6934, -18.4038]],
   > device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)
   > **targets**
   > tensor([ 2842,  1353,   118,   108,   425,   168,  2123,  9758,  6036,   748,
   > 443,     1,   102, 12102,  2115,   450,    96,  5147,   998,  1227,
   > 220,   177,  8876,    32,    79,  9920,    65,    43,  1468,    84,
   > 8002,    13], device='cuda:0')
   > out
   > tensor([[-14.9549, -14.1026, -15.7504,  ..., -19.3176, -22.6721, -18.4659],
   > [-11.7263, -12.5097, -15.5440,  ..., -19.5593, -22.9155, -20.5102],
   > [ -4.3821,  -9.7733,  -3.9627,  ..., -11.9340, -11.7187, -12.0451],
   > [ -6.1771,  -7.6977,  -5.3471,  ..., -11.8034, -11.9683, -13.8230],
   > [-15.3451, -16.2378, -16.4004,  ..., -20.1262, -22.6535, -20.3700],
   > [-14.6429, -15.8015, -15.3850,  ..., -19.8169, -22.2832, -18.9964]],
   > device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)
   > targets
   > tensor([ 8923,  2130,  4607, 12931,   341,    47], device='cuda:0')

I am adding this accuracy thing in train_pipeline(train)

Please could anyone help me with it,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add more details about which "weird errors" you are getting? The exact error traceback would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you could provide details about "out" and "targets" like shape of the tensors and datatypes (float or int), etc., instead of providing a link to the entire notebook, which is huge. You may get errors or unexpected results if "out" or "targets" are floating point values. You could update your question with more details and let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi @AravindG. I have updated the same, could you please check now

Comment: You haven't mentioned the shapes and dtypes of "out" and "targets" tensors. Could you add that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided details about the exact shapes and datatypes of `out` and `targets` tensors, I can only provide the approach, you have to figure out the exact code.

If you are using softmax at the end of your model, then `out` should be a tensor of size `(n_classes, 1)` containing the probabilities of the datapoint belonging to each class. You have to convert that vector of probabilities to the corresponding integer class label, and store it in (say) `out_labels`.

Also ensure that `targets` is an integer tensor, and contains the correct integer class labels.

After above steps, you can compute accuracy like this -

```
accuracy = (out_labels == targets).sum() / len(targets)
```

(Make sure both `out_labels` and `targets` are integer tensors of the same shapes to avoid running into any errors).

Comment: INPUT: image shape: torch.Size([3, 3, 128, 128]) target: tensor([7717, 3538,   71], device='cuda:0')